# Touch move and resize layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I see on the Galaxy Tab Email app or in My Files app (run on galaxy tab). The user can touch on a vertical line and move, the listview size change following user touch moving.
Like this video :
[Galaxy_tab_email_app](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xfRKau3uDI&list=HL1348664439&feature=mh_lolz)

I see that when user touch on the edge of the listview. A Vertical line appear. Like this image :
[image]

My question are :

1. How can the app appear the line with special red part on the image?
2. How the app resize the listview?

As my guess. The "line view" catch touch action, and when user move his finger, the app resize the listview (or listview's parent layout) size. But I don't know whether we have another way ?

Thank you and sorry because my english is not really well.

Answer (score 1):

A guess, because I don't know how this app does it:

a.  Create a custom view class and have properties which describe x,y, width, height etc. and a property for the y position to draw the pointer  ("special bit in red").

x,y, width, height just describe the position of the bar.  The pointer position is controlled by the listview depending on which item you select.  Override the onDraw() method of the view to draw the bar.  It's not difficult to draw shapes like this on a canvas.

http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193a/06/

b.  Override the onTouch() method of the class and capture drag actions on the bar.  Use an Interface to register callbacks to classes which want to know when the bar is dragged, e.g. the listview on the left and the layout on the right.

Study the custom checkbox example here:

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.co.uk/

Comment: Thank you @Simon. I am too busy now.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Simon. Sorry because I reply you too late.
I am too busy now. I will try your suggest and post the result later.